# C# Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

Tags: c#

Ошибка происходит в программе Visual Studio(Windows Forms) когда подключаюсь/пытаюсь войти/зарегистрировать нового пользователя на локальном сервере к базе данных.

[image: Вот ошибка]

```
class DB
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=;port=;username=;password=;database="); //я здесь ввожу данные

    public void openConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open(); // В данной строке выдает ошибку
    }
    public void closeConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }
    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Перепроверьте корректность вводимых данных, используйте стороннюю программу для подключения к БД для проверки, например LINQPad.

Comment: Ssl connection error? Зачем вам шифрование при подключении а бд? Отключите его ssl_mode=DISABLED.